# Is it possible to pretty print Awk's code?

Tags: awk, gnu, pretty-print

Quite often I find myself writing [Awk one-liners](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38972737/1983854) that gain complexity over time.

I know I can always create an Awk file where to keep adding use cases, but it is certainly not as usable as changing the text on the command line.

For this: is there any way I can pretty print Awk's code, so I can make more sense out of it?

For example, given this:

```
awk 'flag{ if (/PAT2/){printf "%s", buf; flag=0; buf=""} else buf = buf $0 ORS}; /PAT1/{flag=1}' file
```

How can I get something a bit more readable?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Ed Morton showed me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55698883/1983854) that GNU awk has the `-o` option to pretty print:

> [GNU Awk User's Guide, on **Options**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Options)
>
> **-o[file]**
>   **--pretty-print[=file]**
>
> Enable pretty-printing of awk programs. Implies `--no-optimize`. By default, the output program is created in a file named `awkprof.out` (see [Profiling](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Profiling)). The optional *file* argument allows you to specify a different file name for the output. No space is allowed between the `-o` and *file*, if *file* is supplied.
>
> NOTE: In the past, this option would also execute your program. This is no longer the case.

So the key here is to use `-o`, with:

- nothing if we want the output to be stored automatically in "awkprof.out".
- `-` to have the output in stdout.
- `file` to have the output stored in a file called *file*.

See it live:

```
$ gawk -o- 'BEGIN {print 1} END {print 2}'
BEGIN {
    print 1
}

END {
    print 2
}
```

Or:

```
$ gawk -o- 'flag{ if (/PAT2/){printf "%s", buf; flag=0; buf=""} else buf = buf $0 ORS}; /PAT1/{flag=1}' file
flag {
    if (/PAT2/) {
        printf "%s", buf
        flag = 0
        buf = ""
    } else {
        buf = buf $0 ORS
    }
}

/PAT1/ {
    flag = 1
}
```

Comment: Noice! But is there a counter operation for converting to one-liner?

Comment: @JamesBrown piping to `tr -d '\n' | tr -s ' '` (removing new lines and squeezing spaces) :P

Comment: Out of humor, I cannot see @JamesBrown any option for this in the manual.

Comment: (`tr '\n' ';'` :) Yeah, me neither—then again I never saw the `-o` either... :D

Comment: @JamesBrown `tr '\n' ';'` would corrupt scripts with lines that end in `\\`. So, thankfully, no :-). (or more accurately - it's non-trivial and let's not try to invent a one-liner generator!)

Comment: **If you don't have GNU awk** you can use a C beautifier (e.g. there's an online one at https://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier you can copy/paste the script `BEGIN {print 1} END {print 2}` into and it'll show the same output as `gawk -o`) to get an idea of a reasonable layout. It's not perfect but better than nothing.